# How to reload a UIViewcontroller from background process in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, reload

Currently i am working in simple iphone application, Get current device region to display in a textfield, when i changed the region app run time, press home button the app goes background process, then i select the any region, again open the app from background the region cannot change in that textfield, but navigate another screen then comes to previous screen the region changed, but i want no navigate to any other screen, region changed automatically, so how to reload the `UIViewController`, please any one help me.

Thanks in Advance

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

NSDecimalNumber *amountt = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"10.00"];
    NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatt = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    [currencyFormatt setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [currencyFormatt setLocale:locale];

    NSString *symboll = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[currencyFormatt stringFromNumber:amountt]];
    NSString *getsymbol = [symboll stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"10.00" withString:@""];
    NSString *Getdollarsymbol = [getsymbol stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"10,00" withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"Getdollarsymbol:%@",Getdollarsymbol);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into your app delegate. You can make a call to your UIViewController to update itself from there.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to listen for a notification on

```
UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
```

Via the NSNotificationCenter, this notification will be fired if you app has become active again.

Comment: There is a joke about Notifications and NSMutableDictionary being all you need to write an application. In general, this isn't a good way to do business.